# How to @Provide services with Dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger-2, mvp

I'm using Dagger 2 for DI in my MVP application. The application has different services which are responsible for making requests like getting product data or doing an order.

Most of the time each screen has his own `@Component` interface and `@Module` class and in these modules the corresponding presenters are provided.

In some cases a service is only used by one presenter. In this case I just `@Provide` it in that module. But I have a lot of services which are used multiple times in different presenters. At the moment I have put them all in the `ApplicationModule`, expose them in the `ApplicationComponent` and add a dependency to `ApplicationComponent` in the 'screen components' if their presenters need one of the services. Now the problem is, that almost every component is depending on `ApplicationComponent`, which I think is wrong.

How can I handle this the best way? Should I create a module for each service and add it to the components that need it? I also want to keep scoping in mind and think the services should be added to the `@Singleton` scope.

**ApplicationComponent**

```java
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class, ContextModule.class}
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    void inject(MyApplication application);

    Context getContext();
    ProductDataService getProductDataService();
    AnalyticsService getAnalyticsService();
    CartService getCartService();
    ...
}
```

**ApplicationModule**

```java
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

    @Provides
    static ProductDataService provideProductDataService(ProductDataServiceImpl productDataService) {
        return productDataService;
    }

    @Provides
    static AnalyticsService provideAnalyticsService(AnalyticsServiceImpl analyticsService) {
        return analyticsService;
    }

    @Provides
    static CartService provideCartService(CartServiceImpl cartService) {
        return cartService;
    }

    ...
}
```

**ProductDataServiceImpl**

```java
@Singleton
public class ProductDataServiceImpl implements ProductDataService {

    private WebService webService;

    @Inject
    public ProductDataServiceImpl(WebService webService) {
        this.webService = webService;
    }

    ...
}
```

**DependentComponent**

```java
@Component(modules = DependentModule.class, dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class)
public interface DependentComponent {

    void inject(MyFragment fragment)
}
```

**DependentModule**

```java
@Module
public class DependentModule {

    private MyView myView;

    public DependentModule(MyView myView) {
        this.myView = myView;
    }

    @Provides
    public MyPresenter provideMyPresenter(ProductDataService productDataService, AnalyticsService analyticsService) {
        return new MyPresenterImpl(myView, productDataService, analyticsService)
    }
}
```